# Collect tweets with their related tweeters

Tags: r

I am doing text mining on tweets,I have collected random tweets form different accounts about some topic, I transformed the tweets into data frame, I was able to find the most frequent tweeters among those tweets(by using the column "screenName")... like those tweets:

> [1] "ISCSP_ORG: #cybercrime NetSafe publishes guide to phishing:
>   Auckland, Monday 04 June 2013 – Most New Zealanders will have...
>   http://t.co/dFLyOO0Djf"
>
> [1] "ISCSP_ORG: #cybercrime Business Briefs: MILL CREEK — H.M. Jackson
>   High School DECA chapter members earned the organizatio...
>   http://t.co/auqL6mP7AQ"
>
> [1] "BNDarticles: How do you protect your #smallbiz from #cybercrime? 
>   Here are the top 3 new ways they get in & how to stop them.
>   http://t.co/DME9q30mcu"
>
> [1] "TweetMoNowNa: RT @jamescollinss: @senatormbishop It's the same
>   problem I've been having in my fight against #cybercrime. \"Vested
>   Interests\" - Tell me if …"
>
> [1] "jamescollinss: @senatormbishop It's the same problem I've been
>   having in my fight against #cybercrime. \"Vested Interests\" - Tell me
>   if you work out a way!"

there are different tweeters have sent many tweets (in the collected dataset)

Now , I want to collect/group the related tweets for their corresponding tweeters/user..
Is there any way to do it using R ?? any suggestion? your help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Please add some [example data](http://$SITEURL$/q/5963269/1036500) to your question, that will make it easier for people to help you. Try editing your question and pasting in `dput(head(yourdata))`. You'll also get quicker and more relevant answers if you show the code for what you've already tried and show what your desired output would look like.